# Make a door in windows 8 app using xaml and c#

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have one grid and two stackpanels.I already made animation to open the door in blend the having problem in setting the door in different resolution.
Here is my code which works fine in 1024,768 resolution.

```
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/left.jpg"></ImageBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" Width="512" Height="{Binding ElementName=mygrid,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/right.jpg"></ImageBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>``
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--used for calculating height and width of door-->
    <Grid x:Name="Door" Grid.Column="0"  ></Grid>

    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="stackPanel1" Width="{Binding ElementName=Door,Path=ActualWidth}"  Height="{Binding ElementName=Door,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/left.jpg" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="stackPanel2" Width="{Binding ElementName=Door,Path=ActualWidth}"  Height="{Binding ElementName=Door,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/right.jpg" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```